# IntelliJ is not letting me run my Java code, src folder is not blue after uploading file to git repo

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is the initial error;
[intelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYkE2.png)

I cannot get the option to run my code using intelliJ after uploading my file to the github repository. Can anyone help? By the way i use linux.

after selecting the correct sdk this is what is displayed[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alVnh.png)

i have now changed the source directory to src so the folder is now blue. When i go to run the project i get this error;
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alVnh.png)

Comment: "Project SDK is not defined" probably has something to do with it.

Comment: how would i go about changing this? it worked before i uploaded my file to github. Then when i cloned the repo and tried to run this "project SDK is not defined" appeared.

Comment: Don't you have a "Fix" link on the far right of that warning message? Other than that,  try `File > Project Structure` then there should be a section to set up your SDK.

Comment: You should learn how to use Gradle: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html

Comment: My lecturers put all of the work on github so we have been almost forced to learn it. Is gradle used more in industry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up the JDK in the project structure <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. Also you need to mark the directory (usually `main`) as a sources root:

[image]

Then IDE will recognize the files inside that directory as a java classes

Comment: I have done this and tried to run it but i got this error; (see error in edit above)

Comment: @JakeMellor just specify the output directory in project structure dialog. In your case it is most probably `out` directory

Comment: ive sorted it, thank you. I specified the output directory and then i got an error which was basically because i had the wrong language level selected (10). I changed it to 8 and the project is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If any folder other than `java` folder is marked as blue. Follow below steps to rectify it

1. Right click on the folder marked as blue. `Marked as Directory` -> `Exclude`
2. Right click on `java folder` and then `Marked as Directory` -> `Sources Root`
3. Right click on the folder in use at point 1. Now `Marked as Directory` -> `Cancel Exclusion`